# Acquired taste auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich suche eine knappe Übersetzung für "acquired taste", also wenn jemandem etwas schmeckt, was ihm als Kind nicht geschmeckt hat, zum Beispiel Kaffee, Bier oder scharfes Essen. Ich suche quasi das Gegenteil von [Geschmacksaversion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschmacksaversion).

Erlernter Geschmack? Erworbener Geschmack? Für beide gibt es ein paar Treffer beim Suchen, aber nichts Definitives.

Oder würde man es besser umschreiben als "an den Geschmack muss man sich erst gewöhnen, bevor man ihn zu schätzen weiß"?

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google returned *gewöhnungsbedürftig* - something one needs to get used to.

As in

> Sushi is an acquired taste

to

> Der Genuss von Sushi is gewöhnungsbedürftig

Another suggestion was *für Kenner* - which really means *for connoisseurs*. Not quite sure about that one, maybe someone can suggest a phrase where you would use *acquired taste* in English but *für Kenner* in German.

Comment: +1 for "gewöhnungsbedürftig"

Comment: Ich finde, *acquired taste* geht in eine minimal andere Richtung als *gewöhnungsbedürftig*, deswegen von mir kein +1.

Comment: @Jan Tja, einige... OK, die meisten, Wörterbücher sind nicht deiner Meinung.

Comment: Wörterbücher können nicht immer alle Nuancen abdecken. Wörter können zwar mehr oder weniger das Gleiche bedeuten aber eher unterschiedlich je nach Sprache verwendet werden. Von dem her mag es schon sein, dass die Wörterbücher die zwei zueinander in Beziehung setzen, und das verstehe ich auch, nur sehe ich die beiden nicht als identisch.

Comment: @Jan Wohl wahr, aber in diesem Fall, stimme ich denen zumindest mal zu. Thomas' "auf den Geschmack kommen" ist auch nicht schlecht, hat aber nicht die Nuance im _Englischen_, welche immer den Unterton von "wer isst denn sowas? OK, ich probier mal. Hmm, ist aber doch gar nicht schlecht." - wobei es nach wie vor anderen graust. Deshalb habe ich Sushi als Beispiel genommen. ;)

Comment: Hm, ist "gewöhnungsbedürftig" nicht mehr ein Euphemismus für "schlecht"? Zum Beispiel: "Das Bier ist ganz schön gewöhnungsbedürfig!"

Comment: @Robert Möglich, aber eben das ist auch oft die Bedeutung von "acquired taste". Der Ausdruck hat oftmals eine _negative connotation_. Z.B. "I love to put mustard on my chocolate doughnuts", "Well, that must be an acquired taste."

Comment: *Acquired taste* sagt für mich aus, dass man es mag, nachdem man sich daran gewöhnt hat, *gewöhnungsbedürftig* hingegen, dass es nicht mehr so schlimm ist. Einmal ist der Eindruck nach der Gewöhnung positiv, das andere mal nur nicht mehr ganz so negativ.

Comment: @Mala Auch, aber nicht nur.

Answer (score 4):

Valid:

"Er/sie/es hat sich an den Geschmack gewöhnt."

"Er/sie/es ist auf den Geschmack gekommen."

This is not used in German:

"Einen Geschmack lernen"

"Einen Geschmack erwerben"